# How to add like functionality on channel entry

Tags: channel-entries

I need the like functionality on channel entry with counter.
Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Do some.e research pls.

Comment: Hi, 

These are two module i found as needed. https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/like
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/likee.

Can someone advise how to implemented because nothing is relation for manual on these links.


Thanks

Comment: Hi, 

These are two module i found as needed. https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/like
& https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/likee.

Can someone advise how to implemented because nothing is relation for manual on these links.


Thanks

Comment: Try them, see what works for you. They're all fairly simple in code you might even get tempted to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from secondary plugins and modules because you never know when the author will stop supporting or updating them.

If you really want to get into visitor interaction, I recommend Solspace's Freeform module. It's a bit complex, but it can be used for polls, surveys, voting and other needs.